# Can I select a form by its action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, liquid

I am trying to bind an event handler to a form. The problem is I don't control the liquid/HTML this is written in. I just have access to it. Because of this the form could have any `id` or `class` but will always have the same action. The HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="/cart" method="post" novalidate class="could be anything">
```

I do have the `submit` button I could also bind too, but it falls into the same category, its always going to `submit` but other than that the id, class, name and text could be just about anything.

```
<button type="submit" id="checkout" name="checkout" class="btn">{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}</button>
```

I'm using jQuery to select the element.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Look up the attribute selector; `$('form[action="/cart"]')`

Comment: perfect! Thank you